# "this" reference of applicationcontext in Spring XML

Tags: java, spring

Is there any way to reference the current application context in a bean config file in Spring?

I am trying to do something like this:

```
<beans
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd">

    <bean id="some-bean-name" class="com.company.SomeClass">
        <constructor-arg>
            <!-- obviously this isn't right -->
            <bean ref=#{this}/>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>
```

The issue is that `SomeClass` needs an ApplicationContext instance in its constructor. Is there any way to get the reference of the ApplicationContext that is loading the beans? I know that I can do all of the loading in the XML, but that is not quite what I am after as I need to do the bean loading in my java code.

Comment: So ideally, your classes would NOT know about ApplicationContext.  That leads itself to service-locator vs doing constructor based injection.  But occasionally you might need it.  Thus the "ApplicationContextAware" (side loading) is the best option.  Just make sure you're asking yourself ~why you need ApplicationContext.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at implementing [`ApplicationContextAware`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/)?  It doesn't come in on the constructor, but it does happen before an `init()` call, and will happen just after bean properties are populated.

> Invoked after population of normal bean properties but before an init
>   callback such as InitializingBean.afterPropertiesSet() or a custom
>   init-method. Invoked after
>   ResourceLoaderAware.setResourceLoader(org.springframework.core.io.ResourceLoader),
>   ApplicationEventPublisherAware.setApplicationEventPublisher(org.springframework.context.ApplicationEventPublisher)
>   and MessageSourceAware, if applicable.

```
public class SomeClass implements ApplicationContextAware {
    //your class definition
    private ApplicationContext myContext;

    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext context) throws BeansException {
        myContext = context;
        //load beans here maybe?
    }
}
```

You can also just `@Autowire(d)` it if using Spring 2.5 or later.

```
public class SomeClass {
    //your class definition
    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext myContext;
}
```

Of course, doing either of these will tie your code to Spring.

Comment: Is there something you have to do in the XML to make this work? I've tried the interface approach and the setter doesn't seem to be getting called.

Comment: `SomeClass` needs to be managed by the `ApplicationContext`.  Either by xml configuration or by annotation configuration.

Comment: I think I see it now, it only works if the beans are Spring loaded, otherwise you have to manually call the setter.\

Comment: Well, you probably wouldn't call the setter yourself.  It is designed by Spring as a way for your Spring managed beans to receive the `ApplicationContext`.  The only place I would expect to see someone call it themselves is if they were building some sort of extension of Spring, and they wanted to provide a similar functionality to their extensions.

Comment: It would be nice if what I was asking for was available, but this works for me. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, I've since realized that I have an unmanaged bean that I probably need to refactor into my bean xml file, but for now what I have will do (it is prototype code).